# Filter a 2d array by another 2d array of rules containing implied AND/OR logic

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have array

```
$rows = [
    ['k'=>1, 'dop1'=>'take', 'dop2' => 'a', 'dat' => '25-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>2, 'dop1'=>'make', 'dop2' => 'b', 'dat' => '26-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>3, 'dop1'=>'sake', 'dop2' => 'c', 'dat' => '27-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>4, 'dop1'=>'bake', 'dop2' => 'd', 'dat' => '28-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>5, 'dop1'=>'dake', 'dop2' => 'e', 'dat' => '29-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>6, 'dop1'=>'jake', 'dop2' => 'f', 'dat' => '30-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>7, 'dop1'=>'ake', 'dop2' => 'g', 'dat' => '24-11-2016']
];
```

and another array for filtering

```
$filters = [
    ['dat', '=', '27-11-2016'],
    ['dop1', '=', "bake"],
    ['dop1', '=', "sake"],
    ['dop1', '=', "take"],
];
```

if the first element of array filters are repeated it will be `OR` expression between them, else will be `AND` expression.
so here the result must be `['k'=>3, 'dop1'=>'sake', 'dop2' => 'c', 'dat' => '27-11-2016']` because `'dat' => '27-11-2016'` exists in filters array and `'dop1'=>'sake''dop1'=>'sake'` also exists. Can you help me, please?

UPDATE
Here is my example of code, but have problem in place where commented.

```
$dop = ['dop1', 'dop2', 'dop3', 'dop4'];
$result = [];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    foreach ($filters as $filter) {
        if(in_array($filter[0], $dop)){
            $new_filter = [];
            $f = explode("\n", $filter[2]);
            foreach ($f as $item) {
                array_push($new_filter, [$filter[0], $filter[1], $item]);
            }


            if(count($result) == 0){
                foreach ($new_filter as $new) {
                    if($row[$new[0]] == $new[2]){
                        array_push($result, ['r' => $row, 'filter' => $new, 'validity' => 'valid']);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                foreach ($new_filter as $new) {
                    for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++){
                        if($result[$i]['filter'][0] == $new[0] && $result[$i]['filter'][1] == $new[1] && $result[$i]['filter'][2] != $new[2]){
                            //array_push($result, ['r' => $row, 'filter' => $new, 'validity' => 'valid']);
                        }
                    }
                }
                $invalid = 1;
                $id = 0;
                foreach ($new_filter as $new) {
                    for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++){
                        if($result[$i]['r'][$new[0]] == $new[2]){
                            $invalid = 0;
                            $id = $i;
                            break 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($invalid == 1){
                    $result[$id]['validity'] = 'invalid';
                }
            }
        } elseif($filter[0] == 'dat') {
            if(count($result) == 0){
                if($row[$filter[0]] == $filter[2]){
                    array_push($result, ['r' => $row, 'filter' => $filter, 'validity' => 'valid']);
                }
            } else {
                if($row[$filter[0]] == $filter[2]){
                    for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++){
                        if($result[$i]['r'][$filter[0]] != $filter[2]){
                            $result[$i]['validity'] = 'invalid';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$c = 0;
foreach ($result as $r) {
    if($r['validity'] == 'valid'){
        $c++;
    }
}
echo $c;
```

Comment: can you try again to phrase the OR and AND part...i'm not completely sure i get it.  your example expected result is good...but please clarify when you are OR and when you are AND.

Comment: I cannot spot your own attempt, so your own code to implement this. How do you expect us to help with that? Please note that we are here to help with _your_ code, not to write your code for you. For that please hire a payed programmer.

Comment: @arkascha sorry, forgot about my own code, I updated question, please help me.

Comment: @WEBjuju I mean if it were in database the request will be something like select * from table where dat = '27-11-2016 and (dop1 = 'take' or dop1 = 'sake' or dop1 = 'bake'), but unfortunately it is in arrays and php

Comment: so you're saying that only element with index 0 is the AND and all others will always be OR...is that right?  (I guess you said that, i just coudn't fathom it).

Comment: @WEBjuju no, elements where indexes are the different is AND and where indexes are the same OR

Comment: however you slice it, my example should get you running with writing you code

Comment: I do not find this question to be very clear.  The [mcve] should show the exact desired result from the two input arrays.  I don't 100% the logical requirements around "and" and "or" conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done some work for you, the bad thing is my way needs an `eval` which can be dangerous, depending on the string you will have in values.

```
$rows = [
    ['k'=>1, 'dop1'=>'take', 'dop2' => 'a', 'dat' => '25-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>2, 'dop1'=>'make', 'dop2' => 'b', 'dat' => '26-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>3, 'dop1'=>'sake', 'dop2' => 'c', 'dat' => '27-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>4, 'dop1'=>'bake', 'dop2' => 'd', 'dat' => '28-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>5, 'dop1'=>'dake', 'dop2' => 'e', 'dat' => '29-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>6, 'dop1'=>'jake', 'dop2' => 'f', 'dat' => '30-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>7, 'dop1'=>'ake', 'dop2' => 'g', 'dat' => '24-11-2016']
];

$filters = [
    ['dat', '=', '27-11-2016'],
    ['dop1', '=', "bake"],
    ['dop1', '=', "sake"],
    ['dop1', '=', "take"],
];


function marrfilter($filters_arr, $rows)
{
    /*
     * Building filters to eval
     */
    $buildFilter = function($key, $op, $val)
    {
        switch($op)
        {
            case '=':
                $op = '==';
                break;
            case '==':
            case '===':
            case '!=':
            case '!==':
            case '>':
            case '>=':
            case '<':
            case '<=':
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception('Unknown operand');
        }

        $val = addslashes($val);

        return '$val ' . $op . " '" . $val . "'";
    };

    $filters = array();
    foreach($filters_arr as $k => $v)
    {
        list($key, $op, $val) = $v;

        if( !isset($filters[$key]) )
        {
            $filters[$key] = $buildFilter($key, $op, $val);
        }
        else
        {
            if( !is_array($filters[$key]) )
            {
                $filters[$key] = array($filters[$key]);
            }

            $filters[$key][] = $buildFilter($key, $op, $val);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Filter function
     */
    $applyFilter = function($row, $fk, $fv)
    {
        if( !array_key_exists($fk, $row) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        $val = $row[$fk];

        if( is_array($fv) )
        {
            $test = false;
            foreach($fv as $ft)
            {
                eval('$test = (' . $ft . ');');

                if( $test ) return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $test = false;
            // that's why you really have to care about what you put in filters and data
            eval('$test = (' . $fv . ');');

            if( $test ) return true;
        }

        return false;
    };

    /*
     * Filtering
     */
    $result = array();
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        $r = array();
        foreach($filters as $fk => $fv)
        {
            $r[] = $applyFilter($row, $fk, $fv);
        }

        $r = array_filter($r);

        if( count($r) == count($filters) )
        {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

See online : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/185658700006fe913e6592a7fc51d4cce0db6a68

First of all I'm building an array of filters that I can use, then I'm applying it to all rows.

---

**EDIT :**

Rebuilt some unappealing parts of the function, removing `eval` to prevent awesome security risks.

- `buildFilter` now return a function returning a simple test depending
  on which op you set (you can even define custom tests)
- `ApplyFilter` modified in consequence

Here is the new code

```
$rows = [
    ['k'=>1, 'dop1'=>'take', 'dop2' => 'a', 'dat' => '25-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>2, 'dop1'=>'make', 'dop2' => 'b', 'dat' => '26-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>3, 'dop1'=>'sake', 'dop2' => 'c', 'dat' => '27-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>4, 'dop1'=>'bake', 'dop2' => 'd', 'dat' => '28-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>5, 'dop1'=>'dake', 'dop2' => 'e', 'dat' => '29-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>6, 'dop1'=>'jake', 'dop2' => 'f', 'dat' => '30-11-2016'],
    ['k'=>7, 'dop1'=>'ake', 'dop2' => 'g', 'dat' => '24-11-2016']
];

$filters = [
    ['dat', '=', '27-11-2016'],
    ['dop1', '=', "bake"],
    ['dop1', '=', "sake"],
    ['dop1', '=', "take"],
];


function marrfilter($filters_arr, $rows)
{
    /*
     * Building filters to eval
     */
    $buildFilter = function($op, $val)
    {
        return function($data) use ($val, $op)
        {
            switch($op)
            {
                case '=':
                case '==':
                    return ($data == $val);
                case '===':
                    return ($data === $val);

                case '!=':
                    return ($data != $val);
                case '!==':
                    return ($data !== $val);

                case '>':
                    return ($data > $val);
                case '>=':
                    return ($data >= $val);

                case '<':
                    return ($data < $val);
                case '<=':
                    return ($data <= $val);

                default:
                    throw new Exception('Unknown operand ' . $op);
            }
        };
    };

    $filters = array();
    foreach($filters_arr as $k => $v)
    {
        list($key, $op, $val) = $v;

        if( !isset($filters[$key]) )
        {
            $filters[$key] = $buildFilter($op, $val);
        }
        else
        {
            if( !is_array($filters[$key]) )
            {
                $filters[$key] = array($filters[$key]);
            }

            $filters[$key][] = $buildFilter($op, $val);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Filter function
     */
    $applyFilter = function($row, $fk, $fv)
    {
        // Key not found in row
        if( !array_key_exists($fk, $row) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Get row[key] value
        $val = $row[$fk];

        // if we have multiple tests for the filter it's an OR
        if( is_array($fv) )
        {
            foreach($fv as $ft)
            {
                if( $ft($val) === true ) return true; // return true if filter passed

                // or continue if not
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( $fv($val) === true ) return true; // return true if filter passed
        }

        // if no filter passed, return false
        return false;
    };

    /*
     * Filtering
     */
    $result = array();
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        $r = array();
        foreach($filters as $fk => $fv)
        {
            $r[] = $applyFilter($row, $fk, $fv);
        }

        $r = array_filter($r);

        if( count($r) == count($filters) )
        {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Please take it only as an example, this is not reliable to find this code in production, took 10 mins to build it ...

Comment: Cool, thanks. Tomorrow, I will test (I have many test versions) and modify it to production. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So without writing the code for you, take a look at [PHP's array_filter()](http://php.net/array_filter)

The psuedo code for what you need will look like this:

```
var_dump(array_filter($rows, function($row) {
  global $filtered;

  $match = 0;

  foreach ($filtered as $index=>$filter) {
    // run code here to determine if this is an OR or AND and apply matching to the $row
    // $row will be like ['k'=>1, 'dop1'=>'take', 'dop2' => 'a', 'dat' => '25-11-2016'],
    // match based on the index of your $filtered ($index===0 AND, otherwise OR)
  }

  return $match;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your asked question appears to only require `=` and `in_array()` logic, so I'll only build a solution for those narrow requirements.  Consolidate your AND/OR logic into fewer total rules, then execute the filtration process with the simplified rules.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CqdKC))

```
$consolidatedFilters = array_reduce(
    $filters,
    function ($result, $row) {
        if (!isset($result[$row[0]])) {
            $result[$row[0]] = $row;
        } else {
            $result[$row[0]][1] = 'in';
            $result[$row[0]][2] = array_merge((array) $result[$row[0]][2], [$row[2]]);
        }
        return $result;
    },
    []
);

var_export(
    array_filter(
        $rows,
        function ($row) use ($consolidatedFilters) {
            foreach($consolidatedFilters as $rule) {
                if (
                    ($rule[1] === '=' && $row[$rule[0]] != $rule[2])
                    || ($rule[1] === 'in' && !in_array($row[$rule[0]], $rule[2]))
                ) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    'k' => 3,
    'dop1' => 'sake',
    'dop2' => 'c',
    'dat' => '27-11-2016',
  ),
)
```